# Geodesic flow on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, ergodic-theory, geodesic

A naive question. I see many research papers on geodesic flows on Riemannian manifolds. Some of them try for instance to show that they are ergodic. It is probably a very broad question but could you give me some general ideas about why is the study of this flow important? And what does the fact that it is ergodic tells us?